# Reload com.apple.springboard.plist without respringing/rebooting (probably with GSSendAppPreferencesChanged?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, jailbreak

I'm developing a jailbreak tool to modify com.apple.springboard.plist and I need to reload this file without respringing/rebooting the device.

I came across to GSSendAppPreferencesChanged (a GraphicsServices method) to reload the preferences (NSUserDefaults) of an application. That's the code I have now:

```
GSSendAppPreferencesChanged(CFSTR("InvertColorsEnabled"), CFSTR("com.apple.springboard"));
```

When I run this code, nothing happens and I get no errors on syslog.

Thanks,

Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of your arguments correct?  I'm only wondering if you should switch the two arguments.  Looking [here](http://pastie.org/559006/wrap), they seem to use the com.apple.springboard string as the first argument.